# Word or phrase that describes a group of acronymic initials that can be any order

Tags: terminology, acronyms

Typical acronyms represent a phrase with a fixed word order. For example, *NATO* (North Atlantic Treaty Organization) is not coherent when reordered to, say, *ATNO* (Atlantic Treaty North Organization).

Yet a form of 'anagrammatic acronyms' exists where each word stands alone and can be represented in any order (although by convention, one order may be culturally dominant):

- Big five personality traits as *OCEAN*, *NEOAC*, *CANOE*, etc;
- The elements of art as *SFTSLVC*, *TFCSSVL*, etc;
- The fire triangle as *OHF*, *HFO*, etc.

> *What do linguists call a collection of word initials that may not mnemonic and can be in any order that pleases the reader or author?*

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Comment: @tchrist This is a stack-specific requirement. Please migrate the requirement from _meta.elu_ to the general ELU help pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commutative = where changing the order of words or item would not affect the outcome or meaning of the phrase or equation.

[Commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), as applied to a binary operation, by extension of logic and grouping would apply to triplets, quadruplets, ... and n-tuplets as well. For example, hierarchical commutation of pairs
((a . b) . c) = ((a . c) . b) = ((c . b) . a) = (a . b . c) = (c . a . b), etc.

> [com•mu•ta•tive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/commutative)  (kŏm′yə-tā′tĭv, kə-myo̅o̅′tə-tĭv)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Relating to, involving, or characterized by substitution, interchange, or exchange.
> 2. Independent of order. Used of a logical or mathematical operation that combines objects or sets of objects two at a time. If a × b = b × a, the operation indicated by × is commutative.
>
> com•mu′ta•tiv′i•ty (kə-myo̅o̅′tə-tĭv′ĭ-tē) n.
>
> commutative (kəˈmjuːtətɪv; ˈkɒmjʊˌteɪtɪv)
>   adj
>
> 1. relating to or involving substitution
> 2. (Mathematics) maths logic
>      a. (of an operator) giving the same result irrespective of the order of the arguments; thus disjunction and addition are commutative but implication and subtraction are not
>      b. relating to this property: the commutative law of addition.
> 3. (Logic) maths logic
>      a. (of an operator) giving the same result irrespective of the order of the arguments; thus disjunction and addition are commutative but implication and subtraction are not
>      b. relating to this property: the commutative law of addition.
>      comˈmutatively adv

For example, commutative grammar of certain synthetic languages, where English have scantly such properties.

- She loved him
- She him loved
- Loved him she
- Loved she him
- Him she loved
- Him loved she

Comment: Please use only IPA for pronunciations on ELU.

Comment: I copied straight from the dictionary page.

Comment: That is no excuse for using an unusable encoding system.  You render your answer completely out of reach of most readers; it is a poor joke perpetrated on credulous Americans, and it does not work.  Use IPA or nothing.

Comment: Even though brought up speaking British English, and continue to write in archaic British style, I am *American* now. If anyone finds us *credulous* and ineffective, then they should stop using Google, Yahoo, or the IPhone, or even the internet. Stop drinking Coca-cola. Whatever.

Answer (score -1):

If I was more of a linguist, I suppose I'd have to scratch my first impulse to call it an 'incoherent jumble'.

To be a little more serious: if the letters can appear in any order, it is no longer an acronym but an *initialism* (particularly if the combination is not readily pronounceable).