# Only requires or requires only

Tags: meaning, grammar, adverb-position, only

I am always unsure about the position of "only" in the sentence. For example:

> This ticket *only costs* 5 dollars.
>   This ticket *costs only* 5 dollars.

Are there any difference? Which one is better?

Comment: Hmmm. Both are correct, and I can't clearly articulate the difference, if any.

Answer (score 3):

I recall my English teachers (30-40 years ago) reminding us that this is an issue of vicinity and affinity.

Additionally, in synthetic languages, the order of words in a phrase is mostly [commutative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/168592/word-or-phrase-that-describes-a-group-of-acronymic-initials-that-can-be-any-orde/168605#168605).

English is said to be an analytic language, rather than being a synthetic language, but does retain some synthetic features. IMO, we should differentiate between portmanteau-istic synthesis of words versus actual grammatical "syntheticalism" of sentences (morpheme synthesis vs grammatical relation synthesis).

Synthetic construction is made possible by the existence of morpheme inflection. Having retained a large repertoire of inflected grammar, synthetic relationship is sometimes still possible in English. For example, at the risk of succumbing to [Yoda grammar](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/yoda-grammar), all the following are equally valid but not equally unusual structures.

- She kissed him.
- She him kissed.
- Kissed him she.
- Kissed she him.
- Him she kissed.
- Him kissed she.

However, the most comprehensive structure in English is direct active [Perpetrator-Action-Target] speech : *She kissed him*.

The only rule you need to use is the rule of best comprehension. Comprehension is affected by the effects of prominence, affinity and vicinity.

- only costs $1.
- costs only $1.
- costs $1 only.

In the above example, if you wish to emphasize being merely $1, when you would place *only* as near as possible to *$1* and in a prominent position - *costs only $1*.

There may be times when you would be in the mood of emphasizing that *costing $1* is the only consideration you have in mind, and you would choose to say *only costs $1*.

There may be times when you would be in the mood to hide being *only* from being prominent, when you would say *costs $1 only*. I believe this sentence structure violates traditional etiquette of clarity in English, and therefore, traditionalists would frown at its use. Though, I do notice its being used frequently in parts of Asia.